# How to find specific string in array or linkedlist

Tags: c++, string, data-structures

I want to find string has a specific short string array or linked list. I make a small program that search conference or workshop like http://dblp.uni-trier.de/ using c++. What I wonder is how to fast search string in an array or linked list. When use string.find() function, I think this function's performance have O(n) time complexity if array's length is n. Can I improve performance lower than O(n)?? Help me, please

Answer (score 0):

For an array, unless it is sorted, the best you can do is O(n) average/worst case because you have to look linearly until you find the desired string. If it is sorted (which would take O(nlog(n)) to do the sorting), you can make it O(log(n)) searching using a binary search. For linked lists, the best you can do, regardless of sorted-ness, is O(n).

Comment: thank you for advance but it's not answer that i want 
I want to find the elements of any array or linked list that contain a particular string. When the string.find () function is used, the time complexity is O (N). How can you increase performance?

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to complicate your code, at each insert to list store pointer to node in some balanced tree.Where nodes will be inserted  based on string from that node comparisions.  Then you can get string in O(logn) time.

If you want to get fast retrievals use hash map it will give you O(1) Time.

Comment: umm.. What i really want to know is all elements of array or linked list that contain specific string or characters. Simple example is
string arr[5] = {apple, bear, watermelon, pineapple, graph} 
i want to find string that contain alphabet 'e'. So I think I need 5 comparisons to do a search. When the number of array elements is N, the search speed is O (N). So I want to know how to increase the search speed.

Comment: To search substring you don't need 5 comparisions but it will be O(mn) comparisions, m length of string n number of strings. It's not possible with array or linked list itself to do it faster.